# Eigen::Vector declare with max entries at compile time?

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to declare an instance of `Eigen::Vector` while specifying the max. number of elements at compile time? For the case of `Eigen::Matrix` it is possible to do it via

```
Eigen::Matrix<int,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::ColMajor,128,128> myMat;
```

but I don't seem to find a way to do it for `Eigen::Vector`. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, what's the use case of that?

Comment: In some real-time contexts you may want to pre-allocate a pool of objects each containing an Eigen::Vector, and you might want to ensure that those objects are in contiguous memory and aid caching. If you know the max. size your Eigen::Vector will ever have and can specify it at compile time, you can guarantee that no resize() will move the Eigen::Vector to a different memory region.

Comment: Does that mean that the maximal dimensions are used for allocation of the object, even though the dimensions presented to the user are possibly smaller? In that case is there really a cache-advantage? I see the advantage of preventing re-allocation, but the cache advantage seems to be heavily diminished, if the actual size is much smaller than the maximal size. I'm writing that not to critisize your design, but to understand the trade-offs of it.

Comment: Say the actual size may fluctuate _at run time_ between 0.5*max_size and max_size. For not too large max_size, a few of those objects could fit into one cache unit only if they had been allocated in a contiguous memory region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eigen::Vector` is just an alias template for an `Eigen::Matrix` of column size 1, without allowing to specifying an argument for the `_MaxRows` template parameter of the aliased `Eigen::Matrix` class template.

> #### [Global matrix typedefs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga2623c0d4641dda067fbdb9a009ef0c91)
>
> ```
> template<typename Type , int Size>
> using     Eigen::Vector = Matrix< Type, Size, 1 >
> ```

You could always setup your own custom alias that would allow forwarding an argument to `_MaxRows`:

```
template<typename Type, int Size, int MaxRows>
using MyMaxSizedVector = Eigen::Matrix< Type, Size, 1, Eigen::ColMajor, MaxRows>;
```